# Select Data from multiple databases?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i access in two different databases at the same time, i mean can i implement a search from database1 and save for example the id or another information to a database2?

Comment: On the same MySQL instance, or separate ones?

Comment: Just use two db handles. Simple as that.

Comment: you mean 2 different connections?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a user account that can access both databases, just prefix the database name:

```
SELECT database1.table1, database2.table2.....
```

as far as I know, you can even do JOINs, although I don't know about possible performance implications.

If you do not have a mySQL account that can access both databases, it's not possible.

Comment: This is assuming he wants to join on two db's in the same query. He can always use two separate db handles and do logic in php.

Comment: I want to search in one database and after the results the user can select one result from the search and another information from the user save in other database, i guess its in 2 different querys

Answer (score 1):

Yes. PHP has a few MySQL extensions. However, if you're just getting started, look at the [MySQL functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) for this. Specifically `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` could be used to create separate connections to different databases or switch between them on the same connection.